# jQuery AJAX request bombs on EmptyResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

This is [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354388/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-call-that-doesnt-return-anything) but this did not solve my problem since this is exactly how I'm handling this.

```
    $("#code").live("change", function() {           
        var data = { codeId: $(this).find(":selected").attr("id") };

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: codeUrl,
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
               // never gets hit if EmptyResult();
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               // never gets hit until page navigation, which aborts this call
            }
        });
    });
```

---

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CodeParameters(int codeId)
    {
        IList<AdjustmentParameter> parameters = GetCodeParameters(codeId);

        if (parameters == null || !parameters.Any())
            return new EmptyResult();

        return PartialView("EditorTemplates/AdjustmentParameters", parameters);
    }
```

Any code that returns HTML works as expected but any code that returns `new EmptyResult()` seems to break the ajax call. Should I be doing something differently? Strangely enough this does not happen on 3 different web servers, only on the public facing server (naturally).

Comment: Where is `new EmptyResult()` in ur code?

Comment: updated... this method def gets hit and def returns properly, just never reaches the success callback

Comment: Is `EmptyResult()` the same as `System.Web.Mvc.EmptyResult()`?

Comment: @Neal - EmptyResult is part of the MVC framework - it is their implementation of the Null Object pattern.

Comment: Have you tried `return new ContentResult();` instead?  I'm thinking the ajax doesn't like whatever .NET is returning in `EmptyResult()`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into an issue in Fire Fox with an EmptyResult. Fixed when I specified the `dataType: 'html'` in the ajax options.

Comment: I was hoping it was something simple like that. Will let you know how it pans out. I wonder what it's inferring the MIME type to be? I guess if it returns `""` or `null` then it might not have any clue how to handle it so it just doesn't? Weird...

Comment: It seemed to grab the `responseXml` instead of `responseText` when the EmptyResult was returned in my scenario.

Comment: That makes more sense but still doesn't explain why the success callback doesn't get hit... or does it?

Comment: Nope it doesn't. The success callback was called for me but a `Document` object came in as the html.